# react-popper incorrect position on mount

Tags: reactjs, popper.js, react-popper

I have built a custom tree view in React, and each item contains a dropdown which is positioned using Popper. Since the child elements are not visible on render, Popper is not positioning the dropdown correctly, for example:

[image]

When the tree is open on mount (i.e the children are visible), the positioning is correct:

[image]

Each level in the tree is rendered via a `CategoryNavItem` component, which essentially looks like this:

```js
<div className={ className.join(' ') }>
    <div className={ `collection-nav_item-link depth${depth}` } style={{ paddingLeft: `${paddingLeft}px`}}>
        <Link to={ linkTo } onClick={() => { setIsOpen(!isOpen) }}>
            <i className="collection-nav_item-link_icon"></i>
            <span className="collection-nav_item-link_text">{ category.name }</span>
        </Link>

        <Dropdown
            toggleClassName="btn-icon-white btn-sm"
            toggleContent={ <Icon name="ellipsis-h" />}
            position="bottom-end"
            size="small"
            items={[ 
                { text: 'Edit category' },
                { text: 'Add subcategory', onClick: (() => { dispatch(openAddSubcategory(category)) }) }
            ]} />
    </div>
    { children }
</div>
```

The `Dropdown` component is where we use Popper, and it works well everywhere else. The visibility of a `CategoryNavItem` is handled via the component's state in React.

Is there any way to trigger Popper's `update()` method programmatically in React? We should force `update` when toggling the item's visibility.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out we just need to expose the `update` property from the `usePopper` hook, and then call it when setting the dropdown's visibility, for example:

```js
const { styles, attributes, update } = usePopper(referenceElement, popperElement, {
    placement: placement,
    modifiers: [
        { name: 'arrow', options: { element: arrowElement } },
        { name: 'offset', options: { offset: [ 0, 3 ] } }
    ]
});
```

And similarly:

```js
const toggleDropdown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setVisible(!visible);
    update();
};
```

Comment: this helped me alot; it wasn't very clear on the hooks documentation of the library on how to use update.  thank you

Comment: The update function is async so you will need to use `await update()` in an async func

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, you can manually update the propper instance so that it recomputes the tooltip position:

> #### Manual update
>
> You can ask Popper to recompute your tooltip's position by running instance.update().
> This method will return a promise, that will be resolved with the updated State, from where you will optionally be able to read the updated positions.
> `const state = await popperInstance.update();`

When clicking on your item visibility toggle, you could add your popper manual update, like the line of code above.

Here is the [reference](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/lifecycle/#manual-update).

Comment: Yes, this works for usual JS implementation, but we do not have access to the popperInstance in React, since it is handled via the Popper provider.